# CSS styling not working when running the MVC application through IIS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am developing a website inASp.Net MVC 5. I want to test this in local IIS (version 8). But when i run / browse the published site, the CSS styling did not work. in my _layout.cshtml file i did not use bundles, instead i use direct link tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

any help.

Many thanks.

Comment: Has the `.css` file been copied across to the server when publishing?

Comment: yes the .css files has been copied in the destination folder.

Comment: what happens when you open the css file directly? Try open it in Chrome for example...

Comment: i just checked that the css files are present in their respective directories, but Chrome showed me empty file. for example i tried to open jquery.min.css and chrome just showed that there is no js code inside the file.

Comment: I think there is a problem with IIS. I put all the css and js files in assets folder which is present in main solution folder and then i linked each required file directly in my _Layout file as mentioned in above question. is it the problem? if yes then may i have to use default script and content folders and bundling?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by just checking the static content option in "Common HTTP Features" group of IIS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The link below provide a more description on the resolution of this problem.
Basically you will need to make sure that Static ***StaticFileModule*** is added to the ***StaticFile*** part within ***Handler Mappings*** in IIS

https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/kb/2196177